# Can mode(), storage.mode() or typeof() return "S3"? Why or why not? (They can return "S4"!)

Tags: r, class, types, storage, mode

One can get `S4` as the result of either of `mode()`, `storage.mode()`, `typeof()` as is shown below.
So, what about the same for `S3`? Why or why not?

```
storing <- function(x) {print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))}

setClass("dummy", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))

S4DummyObject = new("dummy", x=1:20, y=rnorm(20))

storing(S4DummyObject) # "dummy" "S4"    "S4"    "S4"
```

Comment: The documentation for `typeof()` seems pretty clear that the possible values include `S4`, (but only *some* S4 objects) and not S3. The reason is likely that S3 objects are not stored internally in any special way separate from being a thing like a vector or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for `typeof()`, "`mode(x)`, `storage.mode(x)`, `typeof(x)`" don't return `S3` since:
The documentation for `typeof()` seems pretty clear that the possible values include `S4`, (but only some `S4` objects) and not `S3`. (*as joran stated*).
(The reason is likely that `S3` objects are not stored internally in any special way separate from being a thing like a vector or list).

As for "`mode(x)`, `storage.mode(x)`", it can be seen via observing what happens if we  replicate the situation that we obtained `S4` as the returned value from "`mode(x)`, `storage.mode(x)`".

```
new_s3_lst <- function(x, ..., class) {
     stopifnot(is.list(x))
     stopifnot(is.character(class))
     structure(x, ..., class = class)
 } 

new_s3_scalar <- function(..., class) { new_s3_lst(list(...), class = class) }

S3DummyObject = new_s3_scalar(class="dummy")
class(S3DummyObject) # "dummy"
storing <- function(x) {print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))}
storing(S3DummyObject) # "dummy" "list"  "list"  "list"
```

So, one can obtain  `dummy`, `S4`, `S4`, `S4` respectively as the returned value of `class(x)`, `mode(x)`, `storage.mode(x)`, `typeof(x)`; but for `S3`, at most `dummy`, `list`, `list`, `list` respectively can be obtained from `class(x)`, `mode(x)`, `storage.mode(x)`, `typeof(x)`.

Comment: `S3` cannot be obtained, that is OK. but, I think one can get more than `list` as the returned value for an S3 object. Hence, your "at most" seems redundant there.